# Google Tango Point Cloud with No Data

Tags: google-project-tango, tango

After downloading the latest C examples from the [gitrepo](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c), I compiled the point cloud example.

Upon build error, I needed to update the code using the (supposedly) supported TangoPointCloud object (Vega release). Obviously, I was using the TangoXYZij cloud previously and everything worked fine.

However, now my Tango devices does not have any new data upon the call to `TangoSupport_getLatestPointCloudAndNewDataFlag` (which I added).

To be more specific, after calling `TangoSupport_getLatestPointCloudAndNewDataFlag(point_cloud_manager_, &front_cloud_ /* &new_data */);`, there is essential what looks like an empty structure for front_cloud_. As in, `front_cloud_->num_points` is 0, etc..

I am really wondering if someone else has had this problem and if there is a work around.

EDIT: I am using Android Studio 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I just update the tango-examples-c and the example compile and run without problems. Is the example project or some modified version of it?

If you are going from `TangoXYZijk` to `TangoPointCloud`, you need to replace TangoSupport but also the TangoService callback `TangoService_connectOnPointCloudAvailable`. In the callback of this function you need then to call `TangoSupport_updatePointCloud`.

Check the unmodified cpp_point_cloud_example for the details